# How do I enable a VsCode language extension for the notebook editor?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am adding an extension supporting a modified markdown syntax with template tags to vscode. For regular markdown files, this is straight-forward. However, in the notebook editor, I cannot select my new extension language for markdown cells (or any cell for that matter). I also can't seem to find anything on their documentation page or on the web in general regarding this problem short of creating a completely new mode for the notebook editor. I just want to swap the existing markdown highlighter for my modified version and it should work in any notebook.

The grammer file includes the markdown syntax:

```
"patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#template"
        },
        {
            "include": "text.html.markdown"
        }
    ],
```

and the package.json simply specifies a new language with this grammar:

```
"grammars": [
      {
        "language": "cdoctp",
        "scopeName": "source.cdoctp",
        "path":"./syntaxes/cdoc-tp.tmLanguage.json"
      }
    ]
```

I also already tried injecting the grammer (then removing the included markdown syntax) into the  `text.html.markdown` context, however, this didn't work at all. I used `"injectionSelector": "L:text.html.markdown",` and `"injectTo": ["text.html.markdown"],` in package.json.